# Tensorflow Model Evaluation is based on batch size

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a graph in TensorFlow which I've trained based on a batch size of 32 observations over hundreds of epochs. I now want to to predict some new data based on the trained graph so I've saved it and reloaded it but I'm forced to always pass in the same amount of observations as my batch size because I've declared a placeholder in my graph which corresponds to the batch size. How can I make my graph accept any amount of observations?

How should I configure this so that I can train on any amount of observations and then run a different amount later?

Below is a excerpt of some of the important parts of the code.
Building the graph:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, self.image_height,  self.image_width, 1], name="data")

        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, num_labels], name="labels")

        # Layer 1
        W_conv1 = weight_variable([patch_size, patch_size, 1, depth], name="weight_1")
        b_conv1 = bias_variable([depth], name="bias_1")

        h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1, name="conv_1") + b_conv1, name="relu_1")
        h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1, name="pool_1")

        #Layer 2
        #W_conv2 = weight_variable([patch_size, patch_size, depth, depth*2])
        #b_conv2 = bias_variable([depth*2])

        #h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
        #h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

        # Densely Connected Layer
        W_fc1 = weight_variable([self.image_height/4 * self.image_width/2 * depth*2, depth], name="weight_2")
        b_fc1 = bias_variable([depth], name="bias_2")

        h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool1, [-1, self.image_height/2 * self.image_width/2 * depth], name="reshape_1")
        h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1, b_fc1), name="relu_2")

        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob")
        h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob, name="drop_1")

        W_fc2 = weight_variable([depth, num_labels], name="dense_weight")
        b_fc2 = bias_variable([num_labels], name="dense_bias")

        logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2, b_fc2)
        tf.add_to_collection("logits", logits)
        y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_1")
        tf.add_to_collection("y_conv", y_conv)


        with tf.name_scope("cross-entropy") as scope:
            cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, y_, name="cross_entropy_1"))
            ce_summ = tf.scalar_summary("cross entropy", cross_entropy, name="cross_entropy")

        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy, name="min_adam_1")

        with tf.name_scope("prediction") as scope:
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
            accuracy_summary = tf.scalar_summary("accuracy", accuracy, name="accuracy_summary")

        merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
```

Loading and running new data

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
            new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./simple_model/one-layer-50.meta')
            new_saver.restore(sess, './simple_model/one-layer-50')
            logger.info("Model restored")
            image, _ = tf_nn.reformat(images, None, 3)

            x_image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[image.shape[0], 28, 28, 1],
                                     name="data")
            keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob")

            feed_dict = {x_image: image, keep_prob: .01}
            y_ = tf.get_collection("y_")
            prediction = sess.run(y_, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: Hey, With reference to your second code block, you are accessing the placeholder `y_` which is for labels in the graph. How will this help in evaluating model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define your placeholders to have flexible size on one of the dimensions by using `None` instead of a specific number like this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.image_height,  self.image_width, 1], name="data")

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_labels], name="labels")
```

Edit: There's [a section in the TensorFlow faq about this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/resources/faq.html#how_do_i_build_a_graph_that_works_with_variable_batch_sizes).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the quick, simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

My approach would have been to define batch_size as a tf.variable and then feed the value of the batchsize you want to use when running the session. This has worked fine for me in the past, but I guess the solution by [Stryke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118173/styrke) would be more elegant.

Comment: Thank you! I marked the answer from @Styrke as correct as it works and fits how I phrased the question but this would also have worked.